# Error of "undefined method for [method] []:Array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on building an e-mail notification system in Rails for users who are tracking particular districts. If I add report to a candidate who is running for that district (that the end user is subscribed to), they are supposed to receive an e-mail alert, if they have those notifications turned on.

Each report has a method to determine add each users to an array if they are tracking the district that candidate is in:

```
def district_followers
    district_followers = []
    if self.district.at_large_district == false
      district_followers << self.district.followers
    elsif self.district.at_large_district == true
      self.district.jurisdiction.districts.each do |district|
        district_followers << district.followers
      end
    end
    return district_followers
end
```

In the console, if I run that method on a report, I successfully get the list of users who qualify.

On my reports controller, I have:

```
def create
@report = Report.new(report_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @report.save
    @report.district_followers.uniq.each do |user|
      if user.notify_when_new_report? 
        ReportMailer.with(user: user, report: @report).tracked_report.deliver
      end
    end
    format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @report }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

However, when I add a new report to that candidate, I get:

```
undefined method `notify_when_new_report?' for []:Array
```

I have tried ways to tinker with this, but the fact that it works fine in the console but not elsewhere is what is most frustrating.

Comment: Your `Report#district_followers` seems to be returning an array of arrays. I am 99% sure that if you try to replicate your controller code in the console, it'll fail with the same error.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Thank you. That was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is why that exception is happening:

```
[1] pry(main)> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[2] pry(main)> b=[4,5,6]
=> [4, 5, 6]
[3] pry(main)> a << b
=> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

What you need is:

```
[5] pry(main)> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[6] pry(main)> b=[4,5,6]
=> [4, 5, 6]
[7] pry(main)> a + b
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So just change that `def district_followers` to use `+=` instead of `<<`